# How does nondeterminism affect the power of a machine?

Tags: turing-machines, finite-automata, turing-completeness

For example, in finite-state machines (FSM), the main difference between a deterministic (DFA) and a non-deterministic machine (NFA) is that there are possibly more branches or outputs for each input, depending on how a machine the machine was built. In terms of computational power, are these two the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For finite state machines:**

Since the non-determinstic behaviour can be simulated via the deterministic version of the machine where new states are created for all possible combinations of simultaneous states of the non-determinstic one. There is no added computational power for reaching for the non-deterministic one. NFA and DFA are just as powerful as each other. However it can sometimes be more memory efficient to stick with the non-determinstic one, so you can avoid an explosion in the number of states.

**For pushdown automata:**

NPDA is more computationally powerful than DPDA.

**For Turing machines:**

Both deterministic and non-determinstic are equal is computational power.

One real world example for the Turing machine would be Windows 3.11. It can run multiple programs at once on a single CPU with a single thread. However if one program locked up, then all programs locked up.